# Are there any ROMs (other than CM and MIUI) for the HP Touchpad?

Tags: custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I'm looking for a ROM which is closer to stock Android for my HP Touchpad and haven't had much luck finding any information for ROMs other than CM and MIUI.  Is there anyone out there who's working on a AOSP ROM which hasn't been modded too heavily (aside from making it work, obviously)?

Comment: Sorry, we don't do individual ROM recommendations/finding.  I think the FAQ has been clarified somewhat since the last time I remember you being around, it mentions recommendations being off-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also be interested in [AOKP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1537636) ROM for the Touchpad.  It's a derivative of AOSP, with some CM.